# Using SPServices to query large lists and avoiding the List View Threshold... feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

So I have a list that will have tens of thousand of items in it which I will need to perform queries upon using SPServices. The threshold is set to 8,000 so I'm having an issue with that.

So far I have tried optimizing the list by putting items into folders and indexing columns that I will be using in queries.

It appears that the only real trick to getting it to work is by properly indexing columns: however even with columns indexed I still have issues:

if I index the columns "Keyword1" and "Keyword2" I can query the list just fine if I only use one of those fields in the query, but as soon as I include both of them within my Where clause with an Or predicate, I get the threshold error.

The last couple of sentences here highlights the problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx "In this case, you could avoid the issue by indexing the Title field. This would enable SharePoint to determine the top 100 items sorted by title from the index without scanning all 10,000 list items in the database. **The same concepts that apply to sort operations also apply to where clauses and join predicates in list queries.** Careful use of column indexing can mitigate many large list performance issues and help you to avoid query throttling limits."

How can I index columns in such a way that I can perform a more complex query such as,

```
<Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Keyword1' /><Value Type='Text'>TEST1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Keyword2' /><Value Type='Text'>TEST2</Value></Eq></Or></Where></Query>
```

I have tried a lot of options. One that I thought was promising was to query the individual folders by specifying the ViewName or FolderName in the query, but that didn't seem to get around the threshold error..

Any tips or alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to increase the list threshhold to higher value?

The work around is to "Override the list view threshold for an individual list by setting the SPList.EnableThrottling property to false.

```
  private static void DisbaleListThrottling()
        {
           using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://YourSiteNameHere.com/TeamSite/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList spList = spWeb.Lists["MyList1"];
                    spList.EnableThrottling = false;
                    spList.Update();
                }
           }
        }
```

You can also use powershell:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://whateverWeb

$list = $web.Lists[“List Title”]

$list.enablethrottling = $false

$lst.update()
```